# RoR View: List results grouped under categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to group a set of products (obtained typing a query) based on taxonomy(on of the attributes of a product)

My desired output is

**Taxonomy 1**

prod1 prod2 prod3 prod4

prod 5 ...

**Taxonomy 2**

pod6 prod7

**Taxonomy 3**

prod8 prod9..

I am using the following code in the view:

```
<% taxonomies.each do |taxonomy|%>           #"taxomonies" is a set of unique taxonomies for retrieved products
  <h1><%= taxonomy%></h1>
  <ul>
  <% collection.each_with_index do |product,i| %>       #"collection" is the list of products retrieved
    <li>
    <%@ptaxon = product.get_taxonomy%>
    <%if @ptaxon == taxonomy%>
      <%code for listing product%>
    <%end%>
    </li>
  <%end%>
</ul>
<%end%>
```

This groups the products based on taxonomies but the format is not what I desire. Could someone please point out my mistake.

**EDIT:** also tried using < br > , but doesn't help!

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaZH1.png) is the output I'm getting. I want the taxonomies earrings, bracelets and necklaces to start from a new line.
Thanks

Comment: You need to set collections for each iteration or grab it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your associations setup correctly, you can do it like this:

```
<% taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
  <%= taxonomy.name %>
  <% taxonomy.products.each do |product| %>
    <%= product.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Models should be something like:

```
class Taxonomy
  has_many :products
end

class Product
  belongs_to :taxonomy
end
```

Comment: grouping is not the issue. I'm able to group the products. But the format in which the results show up in the view is not as desired.

Comment: I have attached an image alon with the question. Thanks

Comment: I think what you want can be done with some CSS styling. Or you can put every `ul` in a `div` so every next `ul` starts on a new line.